# VBA for TableStyle

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to alter the default table style to TableStyleLight9 but my code won't accept it.  Can you please educate me on how to do so?  This is how I set my table up....also would you know why this method places my drop down menu outside the confines of the table?

Thank-you.

```
FinalRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, LastColumn)), , xlYes).Name = "Data"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your macro recorder broken? It's a great source for finding out how to code things. This works for me:

```
Sub test()
FinalRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, LastColumn)), , xlYes).Name = "Data"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

End Sub
```

The dropdowns from the table header take up as much space as they need to. If the table is smaller than the dropdown, it will extend outside the table.

[image]

Comment: "Is your macro recorder broken?"  I like it.  Thanks for the answer and I should have tried the recorder; thanks for the reminder.  I think I forgot that the recorder can be very useful.  Thanks for taking the time to reply and for also explaining the table/dropdown relationship.